# dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system

Tags: dpkg, read-only

I am a newbie in this operating system

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I found it very interesting to use.

Then once I install chromn from ubuntu software I got

```
I/O Error
```

After that I could not install any application.

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I type

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system
```

I have tried many solutions like

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

No used, I am really need your help.

Thank

Answer (score 8):

Try using:

```
sudo mount -o remount /dev/sda1
```

If `sda1` is your hard disk.

Comment: I got this error

mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sda6 read-write, is write-protected

Comment: Can you post the result of: mount -l

Comment: It just show

`mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sda6 read-write, is write-protected`

Comment: Ok, can you create a file? for example doing: touch test and on the other hand, can you paste your /etc/fstab?

Comment: Thank smile, After I delete
`/var/lib/dpkg/lock`
I could install application again

If there are any error I will post it

Comment: Does not work, still read-only. I guess all I can do is booting another Linux mount the partition of this one and remove the lock file manually. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 7):

Try deleting the lock file i.e

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

and then run

```
dpkg --reconfigure -a
```

This error;

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

causes when software upgrade is interrupted.

You can also follow this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46628/not-able-to-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-read-only)!

Comment: I think deleting the lock file do the trick 

After I delete this lock file I could install 

`apt-get install unrar`

Comment: I could not vote you up since I don't have enough reputation 

THank

Comment: I tried to install another software I got 

fopen: Input/output error
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Read-only file system
dpkg: error processing man-db (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to flush updated status of `hicolor-icon-theme': Read-only file system
touch: cannot touch `/var/lib/update-notifier/dpkg-run-stamp': Read-only file system
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: You cannot delete the lock with read-only file system, so this is certainly not a complete solution and I guess the lock will be automatically removed when I make the fs writeable.

Comment: I had to remount the file system as read/write. mount -o remount /dev/dsa1 (if that's the name of your hard drive. df command to see the names of drives).

Comment: says cannot remove Read-only file system; I tried `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock -f`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
sudo mount / -o remount,rw
```

then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both the solutions are half complete I added mine based on them. I had this problem by pressing `ctrl+c` while running a `do-release-upgrade`.

I used `lsblk` or `fdisk -l` to find out which is the partition I need to remount, let's call it `/dev/x` and it was mounted to `/`.

I used `dmesg` to find out whether there was any problem with the partition. I used `fsck /dev/x` to fix errors if there was any and `mount / -o remount,rw` to remount the partition in read & write mode.

After that I run `pkill dpkg` and finally `dpkg --reconfigure -a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if command -v dpkg &>/dev/null;then
      if [ ! -d /var/lib/dpkg ];then
        mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/updates  /var/lib/dpkg/info
        touch /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new
      fi
       dpkg --configure -a
    fi
```