# error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0013' near line 0: EOF after field name

Tags: dpkg

installing ubuntu.desktop failed and I get message

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run sudo dpkg --configure -a to correct.
```

When I run that command I get the following message:

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0013' near line 0: EOF after field name.
```

I'm trying to reinstall the ubuntu.desktop but not sure how to proceed.
any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates; sudo rm 0013
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to move things along, but I'm now stepping thru sudo rm00xx one line at a time. Is that to be expected?

Comment: yes you have to cded into the directory and remove the corresponding file.

Comment: have removed the files it suggested, but now I get an error "not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock and it says run sudo dpkg -configure -a again. Do I remove the lock file from the dir indicated? and actually I get that message after running the sudo get-apt update again which fails to fetch a bunch of http pages with 404 errors

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: alternatives, available, available-old, cmethopt, diversions, diversions-old,info, lock, parts, statoverride, statoverride-old, status, status-old, tmp.ci, triggers, updates

Comment: output of this `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock` command not `ls /var/lib/dpkg`

Comment: -rw-r----- 1 root root 0

Comment: Try the answers in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269856/dpkg-error-unable-to-access-dpkg-status-area-read-only-file-system) question and let me know if the solutions given are worked or not.

Comment: I pretty much got the same answers ending with mount cannot remount block device. I can't rm the var/bin/dpkg/lock. Since I don't really have anything on this vm yet, I think I'm just going to reinstall os. thx for the help along the way