# Fix apt install

Tags: apt, dpkg

I was trying to install something using apt install, but it failed because of insufficient disk space. I have freed up disk space, but now I cannot install anything.

```
sudo apt install emacs
```

gives

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which gives

```
dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
```

reading [dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269856/dpkg-error-unable-to-access-dpkg-status-area-read-only-file-system) I tried

```
rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

which gives

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Read-only file system
```

Trying

```
chmod -r +w /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

gives

```
chmod: cannot access '+w': No such file or directory
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Read-only file system
```

I am running

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

on WSL2.

Comment: The file system has gone read-only, probably due to lack of space. Now that you freed space, have you tried a reboot?

Comment: A RW file-system flips to RO when corruption/errors are discovered to prevent dataloss, so were this a real Ubuntu system I'd suggest booting a *live* system & `fsck` or file-system check your partitions using the appropriate command for your *unstated* file-system. As you're on WSL2 wait for others, but I'd upgrade your system asap as a fully upgraded 20.04 will report as 20.04.4 and not 20.04.1 (ie. your pastes show a system very behind on security upgrades)